# Open Graph story post Object

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post an object from my iOS game. I double check the permissions and I copy and paste the code Facebook gave me, and it doesn't work :S

any idea?

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *object =
[FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"game:level"
                                        title:@"Sample Level 2"
                                        image:@"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png"
                                          url:@"http://samples.ogp.me/367110273423562"
                                  description:@""];;

object[@"create_object"] = @"1";
object[@"fbsdk:create_object"] = @"1";

[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/objects/game:level"
                                   graphObject:object
                             completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                 id result,
                                                 NSError *error) {
                                 // handle the result
                                 NSLog(@"Result: %@",error);
                             }];
```

Error callback:

```
Result: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1690d1d0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            message = "Cannot specify type in both the path and query parameter.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0xae21820, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0xc1279f0, appID: 358605784274011, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0xae227a0>, expirationDate: 2013-12-07 05:14:08 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-10-08 14:48:02 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    "basic_info",
    installed,
    "user_location",
    email,
    "user_friends",
    "user_birthday",
    "publish_actions"
)>}
```

I try to search the solution but I doesn't find it on iOS

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're receiving the error `Cannot specify type in both the path and query parameter` because both the `object` and the `graphPath` parameters contain the object type, i.e. `game:level`. Instead of passing `@"me/objects/game:level"`, just use `@"me"`.

Comment: Yes it success, but you don't get the object Id in the result.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, but solved it by creating the object and action type on the open graph section of the app. For creating the actions and the objects for an refer [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph/). It has a great example for posting the custom stories. And if you have already created the objects and the actions then recheck for the namespace and calling of the actions on the objects.